# Remover sub diretórios com htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

Eu tenho um site exemplo.com que possuía um subdiretório chamado /lojanova.

Esse site foi inteiro migrado para a raiz do diretório principal: "/".

Para o google ainda existem algumas imagens e arquivos que estão sendo direcionados para o domínio errado.

Gostaria de realizar um 301 com o htaccess para que todo acesso feito, por exemplo:

http://exemplo.com/lojanova/categoria/produto1.html

vá para http://exemplo.com/categoria/produto1.html

É possível?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que o [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) está habilitado você pode fazer o seguinte no seu .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^lojanova/(.+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^lojanova(/)?$ / [R=301,L]
```

Isso vai gerar um http redirect [301 movido permanentemente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) de qualquer URL "/lojanova/[algo]" para "/[algo]" ou de "/lojanova" para "/".

Comment: Estranho, ainda assim não funcionou. Preciso ter o diretório antigo em questão?

Comment: Acabo recebendo 404 dizendo que a página não existe. De fato, ela não existe mais. Porém gostaria de dizer ao request que ela foi movida para outro endereço.

Comment: @MateusPrado você não precisa ter o diretório antigo e estas regras de rewrite vão exatemente dizer ao request que "/lojanova/algo.html" foi movido para o edenreço "/algo.html" e "/lojanova/categoria/produto1.html" para "/categoria/produto1.html" ou qualquer outra variação. Você checou se o mod_rewrite está habilitado no seu apache? poste mais detalhes do que fez.

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida resposta BrunoRB. Verifiquei com a hospedagem e eles confirmaram que o mod_rewrite está ativo. Como se trata de uma hospedagem compartilhada não tenho acesso sudo para fazer tal verificação. No entanto, criei o arquivo htaccess copiando e colando aquilo que foi recomendado por você. Vou pegar um servidor meu e efetuar os testes para ver se tenho um resultado diferente e posto aqui.